# clang++ errors while compiling android code on MTK platform

Tags: android

the errors:
clang++.real: error: unable to execute command: Alarm clock
clang++.real: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

what's wrong happend?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sincerely sorry, no codes can be posted here. these errors occurred after the compiling command: mmma <path>.